# Java: specific enums and generic Enum<?> parameters

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, compiler-construction, javac

I want to pass any enum value to method in utility class and get another enum value of same enum type. Something like this:

```
public class XMLUtils {

    public static Enum<?> getEnumAttribute(Element element, String name, 
            Enum<?> defaultValue) {

        if (element.hasAttribute(name)) {
            String valueName = element.getAttribute(name);
            // search for value 
            for (Enum<?> value: defaultValue.getClass().getEnumConstants())
                if (value.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(valueName))
                    return value;
        }
        // not found, return default value
        return defaultValue;
    } 
}
```

Use of method `getEnumAttribute()`:

```
// simple enum
public enum EUploadMethod {
    INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
}

// read enum value from XML config file
EUploadMethod method = XMLUtils.getEnumAttribute(element, "method",
        EUploadMethod.INSERT);
```

This code is fully functional, **Eclipse compiles and runs it without warnings** or errors and it works like a charm.

But when I clean and compile project from command line **by Maven2, it fails with error** on line where is `getEnumAttribute` called:

```
$ mvn clean compile
....
[ERROR] /home/.... DataUploader.java:[173,53] inconvertible types
found   : java.lang.Enum<capture#414 of ?>
required: .....DataUploader.EUploadMethod
```

I am using Sun JDK 1.6 in either Eclipse and Maven:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 21:16:01+0200)
Java version: 1.6.0_14
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.14/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.27-17-generic" arch: "i386" Family: "unix"
```

Questions:

1. Why this code is compilable and **functional in Eclipse**, and compile **fails in Maven** which using as far as I know same javac compiler?
2. What's wrong with passing specific enums to generic `Enum<?>` parameters?

Thanks,

Martin Schayna

Comment: I removed the maven-2 tag as this is not a maven related issue but a pure eclipse/javac compiler issue.

Comment: Eclipse has it's own compiler, independent of the JDK.  That's why it doesn't require the JDK to be installed (you only need the JRE.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Eclipse compiler and javac have some differences, especially when it comes to generics. It is believed that eclipse is correct, but that doesn't matter :)
2. Try

   ```
   public static <T extends Enum<T>> Enum<T> getEnumAttribute(Element element, String name, 
       Enum<T> defaultValue) {
      ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you, you are absolutely right, man! With your alternative method signature is my source compilable either in Eclipse and Maven. I am little confused by differences between both compilers... Anyway, thank you again!

Comment: The constraint `<T extends Enum<T>>` is correct but you could make `T` (the actual enum type) the return type rather than `Enum<T>` which is an abstract superclass of `T`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version of Eclipse you are using but I think it is wrong here.  My version reports the same error that you are seeing with Maven, which appears to be a genuine error.

The problem is that you have two wildcards (`"?"`) in the signature of `getEnumAttribute()` but there is no constraint (nor is it possible to create one) that forces them to be the same.  So a client could pass in an enum of one type as the default value and get an enum of a different type in return.

You can eliminate the error in the calling code by replacing both wildcards with a named type parameter:

```
class XMLUtils {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <E extends Enum<E>> E getEnumAttribute(Element element, String name, 
            E defaultValue) {

        if (element.hasAttribute(name)) {
            String valueName = element.getAttribute(name);
            // search for value 
            for (Enum<?> value: defaultValue.getClass().getEnumConstants())
                if (value.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(valueName))
                    return (E) value;
        }
        // not found, return default value
        return defaultValue;
    } 
}
```

But I don't think it's possible to eliminate the unchecked cast, because `Enum<E>.getClass()` returns `Class<Enum<?>>` so the compiler cannot tell what type of enum is contained in the `enumConstants` array.

Comment: Thank you for theoretical analysis, especialy "unwanted" tolerance to two different enum types (one for `defaultValue` and one for the result) is important, but in my case it probably wouldn't cause many  mistakes.

For completeness: I am using Eclipse 3.5.1.